# What is the correct way to apply np.select() on one row at a time in numpy and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a way of giving a score to each retailer, The retailers should have a score to be clustered later on, but I needed to make a score for each retailer based on his tagged `target`. There are 2 targets:

1. `balanced` This is a general score based on multiple criterias which I will show now in the code
2. `nmv` Which aims at targeting retailers based on how high their nmv is.

Here's the code and what I tried:

```
targets = ['balanced','nmv'] 

day_of_month = date.today().day

df['Score'] = 0

if day_of_month > 10: #If today is greater than the 10th day, do the dynamic targeting. Else, do the first 10 days plan

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        target = row['target']

        if target == 'balanced':
            conditions = [
                (df['retailer_id'].isin(droppers['retailer_id'])), # Dropped From MP 

                (df['months_sr'] > 0.4) | (df['historical_sr'] > 0.4) & (df['orders_this_month_total'] >= 1), 
                
                (df['wallet_amount'] > 0) & (df['orders_this_month_total'] > 0), #Has Wallet Amount and still made no orders this month

                (df['orders_this_month_total'] == 1), # Ordered Once this month,
                
                ( (df[['nmv_this_month_total','nmv_one_month_ago_total','nmv_two_months_ago_total','nmv_three_months_ago_total']].fillna(0).pct_change(axis = 1).mean(axis = 1) ) > 0), # His nmv is making progress

                (df['skus_pct_change_q_cut'].isin(['med','high','extreme'])), # His orders are more likely to contain more than 3 SKUs

                (df['orders_one_month_ago_total'] >= 1) & (df['orders_this_month_total'] <= 1), # Ordered once this month or not at all and ordered last month once or more.

                (df[['orders_one_month_ago_total','orders_two_months_ago_total','orders_three_months_ago_total']].sum(axis = 1) > 0) & (df['orders_this_month_total'] >= 1), # Ordered At least in one of the previous three months and made one order this month

                (df[['orders_one_month_ago_total','orders_two_months_ago_total','orders_three_months_ago_total']].sum(axis = 1) > 0) & (df['orders_this_month_total'] <= 1), # Ordered At least in one of the previous three months and made none orders this month

                (df['sessions_this_month'] > 0) & (df['visits_this_month'] == 0), # Opens the app and we did not pay him a visit.
                
                (df['visits_this_month'] == 0) & (df['peak_week'] == wom) & ((df['months_sr'] >= 0.4) & (df['months_sr'] <= 1)) & (df['orders_this_month_total'] < 4), # This week is his peak week and he made less than 4 orders

                (df['peak_week']  < wom) & (df['orders_this_month_total'] == 0), # Missed their critical week

                (df['wallet_amount'] > 0),

                True
            ]
            results = list(range(len(conditions) - 1, -1, -1))  # define results for balanced target
        
        elif target == 'nmv':
            
            conditions = [
                (df['retailer_id'].isin(droppers['retailer_id'])), # Dropped From MP 
                        
                (df['visits_this_month'] == 0) & (df['peak_week'] == wom) & ((df['months_sr'] >= 0.4) & (df['months_sr'] <= 1)) & (df['orders_this_month_total'] == 0), # This week is his peak week 

                (df['visits_this_month'] == 0) & (df['historical_sr'] >= 0.4) & (df['orders_this_month_total'] == 0), # Overall Strike Rate is greater than 40%

                (df['nmv_q_cut_total'].isin(['high','extreme'])),
                
                (df['nmv_q_cut_total'].isin(['high','extreme'])) & ( (df['wallet_amount'] > 0) | (df['n_offers'] > 0) ),

                (df['months_nmv'].median() >= df['polygon_average_nmv']),

                (df['orders_one_month_ago'] > 0),

                (df['months_sessions_q_cut'] > 0),

                True
            ]
            results = list(range(len(conditions) - 1, -1, -1)) # define results for activation target

        df.loc[index, 'Score'] = np.select(conditions, results)
        df['Score'] = df['Score'].astype(int)

else:

    conditions = [
        (df['retailer_id'].isin(droppers['retailer_id'])), # Dropped From MP 
                
        (df['visits_this_month'] == 0) & (df['peak_week'] == wom) & ((df['months_sr'] >= 0.4) & (df['months_sr'] <= 1)), # This week is his peak week 

        (df['historical_sr'] >= 0.4), # Overall Strike Rate is greater than 40%
        
        (df['orders_one_month_ago'].isin([1,2,3,4])) & (df['nmv_one_month_ago'] >= 1500), 

        (df['orders_one_month_ago'].isin([1,2,3,4])),

        (df['orders_two_months_ago'].isin([1,2,3,4])),

        (df['orders_three_months_ago'].isin([1,2,3,4])),

        (df['last_visit_date'].dt.year == 2022) & (df['last_order_date'].dt.year == 2022), # Last Order Date And last Visit Date is in 2022

        (df['last_visit_date'].dt.year == 2023) & (df['last_order_date'].dt.year == 2023),
        
        True
    ]

    results = list(range(len(conditions) - 1, -1, -1))

    df['Score'] = np.select(conditions, results)
```

As you can see, I gave a score to each retailer, it used to work before, I though that if I iterate through the rows of the dataframe and assign a score it will give me the final score for that retailer under this specific target.
However, it returns a list (I suppose) from the error:

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Can you show me the correct way to use `np.select` on individual rows?

Comment: I am not sure I understand properly. But why are you iterating over rows and then calculate the condition over the whole dataframe? If there are only targets then doing this twice would be sufficient and would most likely also resolve your list issues.

Comment: @LukasHestermeyer I don't want the whole df.
All I want is that I give multiple conditions, if the currently iterated retailer's target is either balanced or nmv to get back what the retailer score (Whichever value he will be assigned to) Each retailer can have only one target.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, your score is just the reversed index of the condition that applied. I would set the `Score` to None as default, and then apply the rules from least important to most important one after another, setting each `Score` individually.

I think the issue is that you are iterating over the whole dataframe, while that seems unnecessary. As there is no example data provided, I can only give a dummy example of what I would do:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': range(20), 'target': ['balanced', 'nmv']*10, 'B': [1,2,3,4]*5}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['score'] = None
df.loc[(df['target'] == 'nmv') & (df['B'] % 2 == 0), 'score'] = 7
df.loc[(df['target'] == 'nmv') & (df['B'] % 2 == 1), 'score'] = 8 # not hit in this scenario
df.loc[(df['target'] == 'balanced') & (df['B'] == 1), 'score'] = 9
df.loc[(df['target'] == 'balanced') & (df['B'] == 3), 'score'] = 10


print(df)
```

yields:

```
     A    target  B score
0    0  balanced  1     9
1    1       nmv  2     7
2    2  balanced  3    10
3    3       nmv  4     7
4    4  balanced  1     9
5    5       nmv  2     7
6    6  balanced  3    10
7    7       nmv  4     7
8    8  balanced  1     9
9    9       nmv  2     7
10  10  balanced  3    10
11  11       nmv  4     7
12  12  balanced  1     9
13  13       nmv  2     7
14  14  balanced  3    10
15  15       nmv  4     7
16  16  balanced  1     9
17  17       nmv  2     7
18  18  balanced  3    10
19  19       nmv  4     7
```

Keeping this order ensures that higher scores will overwrite lower scores. Entries that are not hit by any rule will be None, but could easily be set to 0 by initializing to 0.

To help you better, it would be beneficial if you could provide sample data.